# Is there a way to programmatically check success of AWS EMR job as part of continuous integration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, amazon-emr, continuous-deployment

I am working on some code which involves a script `my_script.sh`, which includes

```
aws emr create-cluster \
  --name "${JOB_NAME}" \
  <some other flags>
  --auto-terminate \
  --steps \
  <some steps>
```

If I then log on to AWS and select 'EMR' services, I can see whether the job ran successfully or not.

BUT it would be nice to be able to get this information programmatically, to check it works. I could then add this to my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

So, is there a way to programmatically get the state of an AWS EMR job during continuous integration? Otherwise, how can I test that my bash script (which launches the cluster) works as expected without having to do it manually with each code change?

Answer (score 0):

Cluster status is an accessible parameter, and there are a few ways you can access it depending on how you want to implement the solution.

You can use the CLI (or respective SDK of your language of choice) to query for cluster status. Given that you're using bash, this could look like the following:

```
aws emr create-cluster \
  --name "${JOB_NAME}" \
  <some other flags>
  --auto-terminate \
  --steps \
  <some steps>

aws emr list-clusters --created-after CURRENT-TIME

# pull out CLUSTER-ID for the result of the above CLI call in whatever method you prefer

aws emr describe-cluster --cluster-id CLUSTER-ID

# setup a loop as needed to poll the cluster status as it moves from provisioning to a definite state (active, terminated, etc).
```

Alternatively, given that it seems you aren't keeping EMR clusters around outside of when they're performing jobs, you could use the following to exclusively list clusters in an active state *(STARTING,BOOTSTRAPPING, RUNNING, WAITING, or TERMINATING)*

```
aws emr list-clusters --active
```

If you'd prefer a pubsub approach, you could also setup [CloudWatch alarms for the EMR job](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html#UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics_MetricsReported). This tutorial demonstrates how you can [setup an SNS topic that another application can subscribe to](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/alarm-emr-cluster-change/) in order to receive status updates for your EMR job as the state changes.

Regardless of your choice, if you want more granular insight into cluster status or behavior, you have a [wide variety of metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/UsingEMR_ViewingMetrics.html) you can either setup CloudWatch alarms for, or poll directly.